# CGI site doesn't starts on IIS

Tags: php, iis, server

Have trouble with starting PHP project on IIS. Read the instructions how to set up a php and everything was good but last step - website doesn't starts.
I have C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PHPSites\index.php
web.config was automatically created in PHPSites, so that IIS can connect to that folder.
Website is added in inetmgr.exe. Other (.NET) projects start well, but when I open http://phpsites/index.php, get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: The URL you used is obviously invalid. You will have to learn what is an IIS site and its bindings.

Comment: @LexLi , it means that the IIS's button "View site" doesn't work right? It opens that URL. What URL should i open?

Comment: you filled in an invalid value of phpsites as host name and expected IIS to correct that for you? No, nothing is that smart.

Comment: @LexLi Can you answer more specific? What the view url must have? The name of the folder (i understand that it is random) and the url I open was specified in instruction.